# Dropbox sync api implementation for android application

Tags: android, dropbox, dropbox-api

how can I use sync api provided by dropbox to download songs and other files from dropbox to my device's sd card.
The documentation says that we should use **DbxFileSystem.open(path);** .

Has anyone implemented this api?

Comment: Am implementing it currently and am stuck in the same problem. i think this riddle will get solved by `getReadStream()` method. I am not sure, but i will answer this after i complete my Implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted the question to the dropbox forum and the reply was:

"Currently, it's not possible to choose the location where local cached data is stored on the Android Sync SDK. However, I'll make sure to pass this along to the team.".

Conclusion: We cannot download a file directly to the external storage.